# Extracting from messy string with regex

Tags: regex, numbers, character, extract

I have string like this: `123#$!=?*ab34AF6?)`

Can you please help me write regex to extract:

1) all numbers, output: `123346` .....

2) all a-zA-Z characters, output: `abAF`

Thanks a lot!

Mike

Comment: Please do your research before asking for help

Comment: What language perhaps?

Comment: you get the output only in separate groups.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Maybe replace all irrelevant matches with empty strings, so the final string is what the OP needs

Comment: 1, then replace not of numbers with empty string. 2. Replace not of [a-zA-Z] with empty string.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yeah, so the regex replacements are `/[^\d]/g -> ''` and `/[^a-zA-Z]/g -> ''`. Whoever that wants the rep can post an answer like now.

Comment: @Unihedron well it's even simpler than that, because `[^\d]` can be expressed as just `\D`

Comment: @Bohemian Good job, if we're golfing the second regex too, use `/[^a-z]/i` ;)

Comment: @Unihedron depends on the (unspecified) language. In java, the flag would be a bogey: `[^a-zA-Z]` vs `(?i)[^a-z]` - it actually *adds* 1 char. I'm a java guy, so I automatically go for that context.

Comment: Thank you all guys, especially Bohemian and Unihedron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st operation: Search for `\D` and replace with nothing.

2nd operation: Search for `[^a-zA-Z]` and replace with nothing.